# Djnago ninja | Trying to send file | no validator found for <class 'django.http.response.HttpResponse'>, see `arbitrary_types_allowed` in Config

Tags: django, mypy

good people,

I'm trying to implement a file download functionality. And the code is pretty straightforward:

```
@api.get("/summary/", response=HttpResponse)
def report_summary(
    request: NinjaRequest, start_date: str, end_date: str
) -> HttpResponse:
    ...
    response = HttpResponse(
        output, # output is the file
        content_type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
    )
    response["Content-Disposition"] = f"attachment; filename={fname}" # fname is the name of the file
    return response
```

But it gives me an error saying during bootup:

```
RuntimeError: no validator found for <class 'django.http.response.HttpResponse'>, see `arbitrary_types_allowed` in Config
```

*I don't want to set `arbitrary_types_allowed`.*

Now how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to: https://github.com/vitalik/django-ninja/issues/424#issuecomment-1099930539

remove this part

```
, response=HttpResponse)
```

**And it actually worked**